# Kendo MVVM create new record with remote datasource

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I think I'm missing something simple, but I can't find any examples showing how to do this... also, please forgive me if some of the terminology I'm using is wrong.

I simply want to use an HTML form that is bound to a Kendo Observable object to create a new record in my remote datasource.

All the examples I've seen show how to edit existing records, but that's not what I'm looking for (at least not at the moment).

I've created a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/matbeard/fYfYz/2/ with a simple cut-down version of what I've got so far. Obviously it won't actually save the record as the create URL doesn't point anywhere, but I'm confident I can handle that.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

And because I can't post a question without it, here's some code copied from the Fiddle:

```
var model = kendo.data.Model.define({
id: "id",
fields: {
    id: { type: 'number' },
    field1: { type: 'string' },
    field2: { type: 'string' },
    field3: { type: 'string' }
}
});

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: 'json',
    transport: {
        create: {
            url: '/myurl/create',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post'
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: 'data',
        model: model
    }
});
});

kendo.bind($("#my-form"), viewModel);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets do it slightly different...

- Your form does not need to (should) be bound to the and object containing the `DataSource` since you are actually not saving the dataSource but one record.

So, you should define the model as:

```
var Model = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "id",
    fields: {
        id: { type: 'number' },
        field1: { type: 'string' },
        field2: { type: 'string' },
        field3: { type: 'string' }
    }
});
```

The `DataSource` now becomes an object per-se:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: 'json',
    transport: {
        create: "/myurl"
    },
    schema: {
        model: Model
    }
});
```

And your observable object has `data` element that is an instance of the `Model` defined (`new Model()`).

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    data: new Model(),
    mySave: function(e){
        console.log("this", this.data);
        dataSource.add(this.data);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

So, your form should be now something like:

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input name="field1" data-bind="value:data.field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" data-bind="value:data.field2" type="text" />
    <input name="field3" data-bind="value:data.field3" type="text" />
    <button data-bind="click: mySave">Save</button>
</form>
```

Your JSFiddle modiefied http://jsfiddle.net/6LHx3/4/

Comment: That's a hell of a lot simpler that I thought. Thanks very much.

Comment: Actually if you are not even thinking about reusing the DataSource you don't even need to use a DataSource and you might issue an Ajax post or define a normal HTML form (no observable object) and let the server manage it. The DataSource, Observable Object,... it is handy when you use the same information in different place of a page and want to get them _automatically_ updated.

Comment: Hi OnaBai. I'm finding the Observable object very useful as I have several drop-down lists bound to remote data -- making a selection updates the values of various other fields. This is simple with the Observable object. However, I have one further question which is hopefully simple... after I've saved the data with `ssowDataSource.add(this.data);` how can I capture the response from the server to get the new records id? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It's okay... I can use the requestEnd function of the dataSource. Thanks for your help.