# Kendo Observable remote datasource update is not being called

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, observable, datasource

I have a HTML bounded form where I load the data from the Kendo Observable datasource read button but if the user updates the form, then clicks the update button, the ViewModel is updated but the datasource never gets updated to send the new data back to the server.

I was using the model, datasource object, and observable similar to this post:
[Kendo MVVM create new record with remote datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857910/kendo-mvvm-create-new-record-with-remote-datasource)

Any ideas on how to get the datasource transport:update to be called to sync to the remote server?

My update is being done with the vsaveupdt button click within the observable as seen below

> Form Model

```
 var formModel = kendo.data.Model.define({                            
                            id: "investigation_id",
                            fields: {     
                                investigation_id: { hidden: true, type: 'number' },                                 
                                sr_number: { type: 'number', editable: true, defaultValue: null, validation: { required: { message: "SR Number cannot be empty" } } },                                
                                ticket_number: {  type: 'string', validation: { required: false} },
                                updt_datetime: { type: 'date', validation: { required: false} },
                                script_name: { type: 'string', editable: true, validation: { required: { message: "SR Number cannot be empty" } } },
                                script_name_chg_ind: { type: 'number', validation: { required: false} },
                                standard_ind: { type: 'number', editable: true, validation: { required: false} },
                                change_type: { type: 'number', editable: true, validation: { required: { message: "Change Type needs selection" } } },
                                change_type_details: { type: 'string', editable: true, validation: { required: false} },
                                resolution_type: { type: 'number', editable: true, validation: { required: false} },
                                resolution_type_details: { type: 'string', editable: true, validation: { required: false} },
                                resolution_subtype: { type: 'number', editable: true, validation: { required: false} },
                                description: { type: 'string', editable: true, validation: { required: { message: "Description cannot be empty" } } },
                                tech_details: { type: 'string', editable: true, validation: { required: { message: "Technical Details cannot be empty" } } },
                                inv_details: { type: 'string', editable: true,validation: { required: { message: "Investigation Details cannot be empty" } } },
                                possible_change: { type: 'string', editable: true, validation: { required: false} },
                                filename: { type: 'string', validation: { required: { message: "Filename cannot be empty" } } },
                                filepath: { type: 'string', validation: { required: { message: "Filepath cannot be empty" } } },
                                test_files: { type: 'string', validation: { required: false} },
                                work_effort: { type: 'string', editable: true, validation: { required: false} }                                
                            }
                        });
```

> Remote DataSource

```
var formSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({                                                                
       transport: {
               read: function(){
                    const sr_number = $('#sr_number');
                    $.ajax({
                          url: "triage_inv/form",
                          dataType: "json",
                          type: 'GET',
                          data: { srNumber : sr_number.val() },                                            
                          complete: function(response) {                                                                                                
                              var res = response.responseJSON;
                              console.log('read reply',res);  
                              console.log('datasource length =',res.length);                                                                                         
                              ...
                           }
                    });   
               },
               create: function(options){
                   $.ajax({
                      url: "triage_inv/form/create",
                      dataType: "json",                                              
                      data: { models: kendo.stringify(options.data.models) },
                      complete: function() {                                                
                          toastr.info('success', 'INV Doc created!');
                          $('button#save').text('Update');                                                                                               
                      }
                   });                                                                                
              },                                    
              update: function(options){                                        
                    const sr_number = $('#sr_number');
                    $.ajax({                                        
                          url: "triage_inv/form/update",
                          dataType: "json",   
 data:{srNumber :sr_number.val(),models:kendo.stringify(options.data.models)               
                          },                                                                                        
                          complete: function() {
                                  toastr.info('success', 'INV Doc updated!');
                                  $('button#save').text('Update');
                          }
                    });
               },
               sort: { field: "open_dt_tm", dir: "asc"}                                    
           },                                                                                                                                                                               
           batch: true,
           schema: {
                     model: formModel                     
           },                                                                                       
           pageSize: 20,
           page: 1,                                                                                                                   
});
```

> Observable

```
var form = kendo.observable({                                                         
      forms: new formModel(),
      standard_ind: 0, change_type: 0,
      resolution_type: 0,resolution_subtype: 0,                              
     getstd: function(){ return this.get("forms.standard_ind"); }, 
     getchg: function(){ return this.get("forms.change_type"); },                                                        
     getrestype: function(){ return this.get("forms.resolution_type"); },
     getresstype: function(){ return this.get("forms.resolution_subtype"); },                              
     vsaveupdt: function(e){                                   
              remoteDataSource.fetch(function(){
                  var data = this.data();
                  console.log('grid data > ',data);
                  const sr_number = $('#sr_number').val();
                 if(sr_number == form.sr_number){
                       $('#tckt_no').text(data.ticket_number);                           
                 }                                    
              });                                
              var njson = this.forms;
              console.log("object->",njson);                                  
              var btntext = $('button#save').text();
              console.log(btntext);
              var std = this.getstd();                                           
              var chg = this.getchg();   
              console.log('save/update chg >',chg) ;                               
              var restype = this.getrestype();
              var resstype = this.getresstype();                                
              var ticketnum = $('#tckt_no').text();                                
              njson.set("standard_ind",std);
              njson.set("change_type",chg);
              njson.set("resolution_type",restype);
              njson.set("resolution_subtype",resstype);
              njson.set("ticket_number",ticketnum);                                  
              if( btntext == 'Update'){
                 console.log('data change ',njson);  
                 form.set("forms",njson);
                 formSource.sync();                 
              }else{     
                 console.log('Save change ',njson);
                 formSource.add(njson);                               
                 formSource.sync();                                    
              }
     },...
```

Comment: You need to call the datasource's sync method once the observable is ready to call the update transport method. Docs: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/sync

Comment: I'm not familiar with vsaveupdt, but if you want to handle the click event of a button then setup the click binding: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/click

Comment: Sync will save any data item changes. So if the observable has been updated, it will be passed to the update transport with you manually having to pass anything.

Comment: so i can see the observable updated, the model, but the datasource.sync is not doing anything to trigger the update transport.. other transport methods are working like read.. but just not the update

Comment: If you get the observable from the datasource using the get method (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/get), update the value of the observable, and then call sync, then it should be invoking the update transport method.

Comment: The observable above form has the forms (model), which is bound to an HTML form, so after I use a button to read the datasource data to populate the HTML form, I update one of the fields on the form, and click the Update (vsaveupdt button) bounded with the click event, the Update function then checks the Model data to pass that to update the datasource via transport (no get method is needed as I am passing it from the form back to the datasource, so it would be more of a set)

Comment: What you should be doing is using the get method, binding the observable to your form using two-way binding, and then calling sync. That away when you update the value in the form, the underlying observable is also changed.

Comment: @David, I do have the form bounded and the observable is getting updated but I need to pass observable data to update the datasource data so it invokes the transport update... Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and answer the question with a dojo example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the datasource insert... method looks to have worked along with the sync method to send data to remote service as it is calling the transport update now. See updated context below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
...
$("#triage_form").on("submit", function(e){                                                                                    
                  var uson = form.forms;
                  uson.set('id',1);
                  console.log('data change ',form.forms);                                                                  
                  formSource.insert(0,uson);                            
                  e.preventDefault();
                  formSource.sync();
 });
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the observable from the datasource using the Get method: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/get

Set the values of the observable are set using the Set method: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model/methods/set

Once the values are set, call the Sync method: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/sync

Here is an example using Kendo's Form widget

```js
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: function(options) {
      // this is just for demo, you'd have your actuall transport setup
      options.success([
        { Id: 1, FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Doe", age: 30 },
        { Id: 2, FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe", age: 33 }
      ]);
    },
    update: function(options) {
      console.log(options);
    }
  },
  schema: {
    model: { id: "Id" }
  }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#edit-form").kendoForm({
    orientation: "vertical",
    formData: {},
    items: [{
      type: "group",
      label: "Edit Form",
      items: [
        { field: "FirstName", label: "First Name", validation: { required: true } },
        { field: "LastName", label: "Last Name", validation: { required: true } },
        { field: "Age", label: { text: "Age", optional: true }, editor: "NumericTextBox", editorOptions: { format: "N0"} }
      ]
    }],
    submit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var viewmodel = dataSource.get(1);
      viewmodel.set("FirstName", e.model.FirstName);
      viewmodel.set("LastName", e.model.LastName);
      viewmodel.set("Age", e.model.Age);
      dataSource.sync();
    }
  });

  var form = $("#edit-form").getKendoForm();
  dataSource.fetch(function() {
    var viewmodel = dataSource.get(1);

    form.setOptions({ formData: viewmodel });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.material-v2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="edit-form"></form>

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Dojo: [Live Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OXoQaToP)

**Update**

Per the OP's request, here is how it would be done without the kendo-ui form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.material-v2.min.css">
  <body>
    <form id="edit-form">
      <input type="text" class="k-textbox" placeholder="First Name" data-bind="value: FirstName" />
      <input type="text" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Last Name" data-bind="value: LastName" />
      <input type="number" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Age"
             data-role="numerictextbox"
             data-format="N0"
             data-min="0"
             data-bind="value: Age">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
          read: function(options) {
            // this is just for demo, you'd have your actuall transport setup
            options.success([
              { Id: 1, FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Doe", Age: 30 },
              { Id: 2, FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe", Age: 33 }
            ]);
          },
          update: function(options) {
            console.log(options);
          }
        },
        schema: {
          model: { id: "Id" }
        }
      });
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $("#edit-form");
        dataSource.fetch(function() {
          var viewmodel = dataSource.get(1);
                    kendo.bind(form, viewmodel);
        });

        $("#edit-form").on("submit", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          dataSource.sync();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this work as I am using HTML form bounded to the observable (form). My remote datasource (formSource) is an object per se, and my observable has data (forms) which is an instance of the model defined?  
I do not see that you used an observable and my model is defined outside of the initialization of the remote datasource (formSource).

Comment: Instead of calling `form.setOptions({ formData: viewmodel });` you could call `kendo.bind($("#my-form"), viewmodel);`

Comment: I guess my main issue is that, I already have the viewModel with kendo.bind but I need to do the update within my vsaveupdt (click bounded event) function but I have tried your above with the get and set events for the datasource data but the datasource data is stating undefined(not sure if it is because my of my datasource being an object).... I was able to update the datasource data with the insert method but the sync method then doesn't do an update transport but instead the create function.

Comment: if you could... would you be able to update your example with an HTML form bounded to show the example above instead of the Kendoform widget

Comment: how would this be done with a remote datasource?  Basically, after I run the read transport with button click to load the form values, edit, then click update button... (Remember that the bounded form model, instance of observable, looks to be updated but not datasource)...The datasource update is still not getting called even though I am using on the submit function and I can see it fall inside the event given the console log but the datasource sync acts like it has no data/undefined so nothing happens.

Comment: @flybeye I used a localized datasource as an example. If you configure the datasource to handle remote requests, when you call `sync` it will see (in the network tab) the endpoint getting hit.